# Oracle schema table name restrictions

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I am looking into using JBoss 5.1.0GA on Oracle, and have seen [this](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/Server_Configuration_Guide/apbs08.html), warning that I should explicitly state the name of the schema into which the TIMERS table should be created, as Oracle doesn't permit the same table name to be used twice, even across schemas.

After reading this, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685775/oracle-same-table-name-on-different-schema) on StackOverflow, and would like some clarification about the hierarchy of objects in Oracle.

Suppose we have a single Oracle database server. Within this, we create two Databases - D1 and D2. Inside each database, we create two schemas - S1 and S2. Inside each schema on each database, we create a single table - T1 through to T4:

```
+-D1
| +---S1
| |   +---T1
| +---S2
|     +---T2
+-D2
  +---S1
  |   +---T3
  +---S2
      +---T4
```

Am I correct in thinking that if I then add another table called T1 inside D1/S2, it will not work because the table names must be unique within the schemas, and T1 already exists in D1/S1, but if I add T1 to either D2/S1 or D2/S2 it will be fine because the two tables named T1 are in different databases?

I have a nasty feeling that my understanding of Oracle schemas is flawed (it is not a database I have used much before) so I'm sorry if I'm asking stupid questions.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the database hierarchical level doesn't exist in Oracle: an instance (set of processes) can only have one database (set of files) mounted at most. Inside a database you will find schemas which are also the same as users in Oracle.

Each schema has an independent namespace, e.g. schemas `S1` and `S2` can both have a table named `T1` in the same database. You would specifically access these tables by using their owner as a prefix: `S1.T1` and `S2.T1`.

Some objects don't have an owner (or their owner is PUBLIC) : Public synonyms and directories for example. The name of these objects will have to be unique in a database obviously. Use public synonyms wisely (=sparingly in my opinion) to avoid name collisions.

Comment: So what does the comment on the RedHat website (the first of the two links) mean then?

Comment: @Rich: maybe `timers` is a public synonym ?

Comment: "However, you need to be careful when accessing either of the tables now if the user you connect with to the database instance has access to both. To unambiguously reference a table in a specific schema, use schema.table." - I assume that that is the problem. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685775/oracle-same-table-name-on-different-schema

Comment: You can have multiple instances run on the same server [ but it isn't generally advised (except maybe for test/dev environments)]. That does allow two databases to run on the same server. In that case there are totally independent and not aware of each other.

Comment: @Gary Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you, but do you mean multiple instances of JBoss or Oracle? I assume you mean Oracle. I think we are likely to go down the path of having one Oracle server with a schema for each JBoss instance (these are running on other boxes), and a user for each JBoss instance. That way there is no risk of ambiguity abuot which table a particular instance should access.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Oracle goes, you can have the same table name in two different schemas.  There may be something specific to the JBoss usage that you were reading about, but it is not an Oracle limitation.